# Loop through Resultset depending on what columns are getting generated

Tags: java, sql, database, resultset

I am working on a multithreaded project in which I need to randomly find `columns` that I will be using in my `SELECT sql` and then I will be executing that SELECT sql query.

After finding those columns-

1. I need to see whether the id is between the valid range, if it in between the Valid Range, then loop around the resultset using those columns from the columnsList and get the data back and store in a variable.
2. else if id is not in the valid range, I need to check I am not getting any data back from the resultset. But somehow if I am getting the data back and flag is true to stop the program, then exit the program. Else if I am getting the data back but flag is false to stop the program, then count how many of those happening.

Below is my code-

```
private volatile int count;

@Override
public void run() {

.....

final String columnsList = getColumns(table.getColumns());
....
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
....
if (Read.endValidRange < id && id < Read.startValidRange) {

    while (rs.next()) {
        for(String column: columnsList.split(",")) {
            System.out.println(column + ": " + rs.getString(column));
        }
    }
} else {
    if(rs.next() && Read.flagTerminate) {
        System.exit(1);
    } else {
        count++;
    }
}

....

}

/**
 * A simple method to get the column names in the order in which it was
 * inserted
 * 
 * @param columns
 * @return
 */
private String getColumns(final List<String> columns) {
    List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(columns);
    Collections.shuffle(copy);

    int rNumber = random.nextInt(columns.size());

    List<String> subList = copy.subList(0, rNumber);
    Collections.sort(subList, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return columns.indexOf(o1) < columns.indexOf(o2) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });
    return StringUtils.join(subList, ",");
}
```

**Problem Statement-**

I am not able to understand how should I iterate through the resultset as every time I will be having different columns in my SELECT sql depending on what is getting generated. And apart from that how can I make it more cleaner in the if else loop.

Comment: I am working on a project in which I need to randomly find columns that I need to use in my SELECT sql and then I will be executing that query. - what?

Comment: `Else if I am getting the data back but flag is false to stop the program, then count how many of those happening.` What happenings are you talking about?

Comment: `else if I am getting the data back but flag is false to stop the program, then count how many of those has happened`. By this I am trying to say just count those potential scenario. And when the program is over, then from the main thread print it out. That's all.

Comment: @Nevzz03: Since this code is shared among multiple threads so it needs proper synchronization to avoid Race condition....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK..
You can have the Randomly generated columns saved in a String array..and then while iterating via resultset you use that array...as follows:
**UPDATE**
You should not include those columns in select statement..Instead you should select all columns in select statement using `*`...and then get the value of that column in rs.next() loop...

```
rs = con.executeQuery("Select * from tablename");
while(rs.next())
{
   for (String col : columnsList )
   {
     System.out.print(rs.get(col));
   }
   System.out.print("\n");
}
```

**UPDATE1**
You need your critical code section written within run() to be wrapped in synchronized block so as to avoid Race Condition as follows:

```
private volatile int count;

@Override
public void run() {

.....
while (!Read.flagTerminate)
{
    synchronized(this)
    {
        if (!Read.flagTerminate)
        {
            String columnsList = getColumns(table.getColumns());
            ....
            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            ....
            if (Read.endValidRange < id && id < Read.startValidRange) 
            {
                while (rs.next()) 
                {
                    for(String column: columnsList.split(",")) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(column + ": " + rs.getString(column));
                    }
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
System.exit(0);//it implies that flag = true;

....

}

/**
 * A simple method to get the column names in the order in which it was
 * inserted
 * 
 * @param columns
 * @return
 */
private String getColumns(final List<String> columns) {
    List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(columns);
    Collections.shuffle(copy);

    int rNumber = random.nextInt(columns.size());

    List<String> subList = copy.subList(0, rNumber);
    Collections.sort(subList, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return columns.indexOf(o1) < columns.indexOf(o2) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });
    return StringUtils.join(subList, ",");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal, that makes sense. What about my second point problem. It is looking very ugly right now as I have made if else loop so many time. Any more cleaner way possible?

Comment: gaping security holes from unsanitized input

Comment: @VishalK sure.  There is no santization being done on the strings that actually get passed into the initial query.  Therefore someone can use SQL injection and iterate over column names that should be hidden.  If you reference my latest update you can see an outline how to attack the problem.

Comment: @VishalK. Can you tell me one more thing. Do I need to use volatile here to get the accurate count?

Comment: @Nevzz03 And the object(that is implementing Runnable ..i Guess) that contains the run() method is being shared by multiple Threads?

Comment: Then yes ..you need to declare `count` as `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
if (Read.endValidRange < id && id < Read.startValidRange) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        for (String column : columnsList.split(",")) {
            System.out.println(column + ": " + rs.getString(column));
        }
    }
} else if (rs.next()) {
    if (Read.flagTerminate) {
        System.exit(1);
    } else {
        count++;
    }
}
```

I have also updated the if-else conditions as per my understanding of the question.

Comment: Thanks Nishant. That makes sense. What about my second point problem. The way I have done currently, it looks very ugly with the way if else loop is setup. Any cleaner way of doing it?

Comment: Because the above code is incomplete I can't figure out the logic. Can you show more core?

Comment: I see. If you read my question, I have two points there, That will tell the full pciture of if else loop. Let me know it is still donesn't make any sense

Comment: What should happen if id is out of range and you're not getting any data back from the resultset?

Comment: That is my second point in the question. I will be having valid id range and non valid id range only. And my program will choose either valid id or non valid id to work on.

Comment: I've updated my answer. As per my understanding there was a change required in the if-else statements.

Comment: Thanks for catching one mistake in one else loop. And in this case I will be needing count as volatile right? as I am running this in the multithreaded code.

Comment: Yes, I believe declaring `count` as `volatile` is correct here.